# Benefit of using redux in Angular2

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I came from Angular 2 background and is now learning React Redux. I have seen people teaching Redux with Angular 2, my question is would there be any benefit for doing so?

To me it seems like whatever Redux can do, I can do with Angular2 using a Service declared at a top level (app.component). I am not an expert in Redux so the whole concept seems overly complicated to me. Can someone please explain why and why I should use Redux to manage state as oppose to creating Singleton in other language or Service in Angular 2?

Comment: The first part of the question is about what the benefit is. That is not opinion based. I'm wondering the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, because essentially Redux is an implementation of a concept for general application. You can use Angular approaches to integrate the Redux concepts with its benefits and drawbacks.

Have a look at [this GitHub project](https://github.com/angular-redux/store), which provides the basic features of Redux, encapsulated in Angular techniques like `Observables`.

This enables you to manage your state following common concepts instead of reinventing the wheel. However, the additional abstraction required by Redux might be too much overhead, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Redux is very much an implementation.  Even the project you linked uses the implementation as an npm dependency.  I think you have it confused with Flux

Comment: Well, you are right...I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ErnieKev please accept, if this answers your question

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question of why to use react in angular and what the benefit is.